# add markers to my OSM .PHP and .JS

Tags: java, php, api, openstreetmap

heey everyone,

I've got a task from my work where I need to put our customer database on a OSM using .PHP and .JS is this possible? And is it possible to get the info rom our database without having the lat and longtitude of the addresses?

I'm also not very good at programming. thx for everyone that tries to help.

Comment: It's surely *possible*, but this may be too big a task to get help on a web site if you don't know much programming. If it's not for learning purposes, consider hiring somebody for the job

Comment: well isn't there any tutorial on the inet u know about since i couldn;t found 1 :( kinda searching for stuff like that or an few advices that could help me a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great number of things you need to learn to be able to build the kind of site you're talking about. You need to know several (not just one) programming language, how relational databases work, how HTML and JavaScript work together, and the many different ways geographic information is processed.

To put it another way, it's like saying "I've been asked to build a house, where can I learn the bricklaying I need?". You're being asked too large a task, especially for an intern.

There is a simple example of overlaying markers on an OSM map,[simple example of overlaying markers on an OSM map](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Openlayers_POI_layer_example) but that needs you to know some JavaScript yourself, which you'll need to learn separately.

got this from someone else on other forum maybe helps other people also still searching for more though if people know some